# c#; Move the scroll bar to the location of the searched word

Tags: c#, find, scrollbar

I wrote the code That find the word in richtextbox.
Now, I want to move scroll bar to location of the searched word.
Please Help me!!!

```
 int j,count = 0;
        string keyword = txtSearchByWords.Text;
        int startPosition = 0; //initializing starting position to search
        int endPosition = 0;
        int endArticle = rtbWords.Text.Length;
        for (j = 0; j < endArticle; j = startPosition)//creating a loop until ending the article
        {
            if (j == -1) //if the loop goes to end of the article then stop
            {
                break;
            }
            startPosition = rtbWords.Find(keyword, startPosition, endArticle, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
            if (startPosition >= 0)     //if match the string                                                         
            {
                count++;//conunting the number of occuerence or match the search string
                rtbWords.SelectionBackColor = Color.Orange;//coloring the matching string in the article
                endPosition = txtSearchByWords.Text.Length;
                startPosition = startPosition + endPosition;//place the starting position at the next word of previously matching string to continue searching.
            }
```

Comment: This looks like just back end logic.  What is the UI for this?  I'm not sure we can help you without seeing the UI code.  Can you please share it?  Is this a web app? WinForms app? UWP app?

Comment: richtext box in winfom of csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ScrollToCaret to scroll to the location of the searched word in rich text box

```
rText.SelectionStart = rtext.Text.Length;//set the start location
rText.ScrollToCaret();
```